# How to undo sudo chmod ugo+wx /

Tags: permissions

I think i followed bad advice and did
sudo chmod ugo+wx /

this was supposed to give me write permissions to my secondary ext4 storage partition but i think i did it for the system partition?
So did i just give myself write and execute permissions outside of home as well?
I bet that's terrible for security?

Please let me know what I did, how to undo it, and how to do it for the data partition instead :)

Thank you!

Comment: only way is reinlstall, really?

Comment: @user228080, did you run it exactly as you show, or did you also use -R?

Comment: Very good point by @psusi. If you did *not* run this recursively, then there's no need to reinstall.

Comment: exactly as shown
so there is hope?
how to undo it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` is the root of all in terms of file systems on your system. The `/` gets 'created' by the kernel at every boot. I think restarting the system just resets the permissions set.

Without rebooting, just reset it to the default (I think) drwxr-xr-x (755):

```
sudo chmod 755 /
```

Comment: What a relief! thank you!
And how to make my data storage writeble by nautilius?

Comment: @user228080 Ask a new question. We ask one question per post on this site :) But really, that has been asked many many times already here, please use the search.